# Debian: umount /media/usb0: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: debian, shell-script, mount, unmounting

I recently moved from Ubuntu 14.10 to Debian Testing. Under Ubuntu I had a shell script for backing up my home folder to a USB stick. The last line of the script unmounts the USB stick. Adapting it to Debian's file system, it should be:

```
umount /media/usb0
```

(or umount `/media/usb` which links to `/media/usb0`). But when I execute the script, this last line throws `umount: /media/usb0: umount failed: Operation not permitted`. Obviously, with `sudo` it works, but I'm wondering why I need to be sudo here (was not necessary on Ubuntu). Any ideas how to circumvent that, so how to unmount the USB stick without being root? (the remaining part of the script runs flawlessly).

**Update**

This is my /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/sklar--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a90bee04-e08a-4a86-8465-762aca5719a4 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/sklar--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant line in your `/etc/fstab`. You probably just need to change a parameter there to allow user unmounting.

Comment: Your /dev/sdb1 has `user` option in `/etc/fstab/`, meaning that can be mounted by users and umounted by the same user that mount-ed it. You should replace `user` with `user=youruser` to always be able to `umount` it as `youruser`. Also, if your USB device is always the same, i recommend replacing `/dev/sdb1` with `UUID="uuidof/dev/sdb1"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `mount` is only allowed for root, or, if specified in `/etc/fstab`, by users.

Now, if you USB drive is auto-mounted without being specified in `/etc/fstab` (or manually by `root`), will not be mounted with `user=youruser` option, so `youruser` will be unable to `umount` it.

If your USB drive is specified in `/etc/fstab` with `user` option, any user will be able to `mount` it, and the same user (and root) will be able to `umount` it.

What you need, is for your USB drive to be specified in `/etc/fstab`, with `user=youruser`. In that case, no matter if `root` or `youruser` mounts the USB drive, `youruser` will be able to `umount` it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are typical lines in `/etc/fstab` for an external USB mass storage device.

```
UUID="4E1AEA7B1AEA6007" /mnt/passport  auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

This particular one happens to be for my Passport USB hard drive. Notice the `user` keyword in the fourth field. This field (the mount options associated with the filesystem) tells the system to allow users to mount and unmount the device. There are other options, but the use of `user` is quite common and typical. The `UUID` is obtained from `blkid`, and is an identifier for the storage device.

For more details, see `man mount`, specifically the section "The non-superuser mounts." This says:

> **The non-superuser mounts.**
>
> Normally,  only  the  superuser  can mount filesystems.
>   However, when `fstab` contains the user option on a line, anybody can
>   mount the corresponding system.
>
> Thus, given a line
>
> ```
>  /dev/cdrom  /cd  iso9660  ro,user,noauto,unhide
> ```
>
> any user can mount the `iso9660` filesystem found on his CDROM using
>   the command
>
> ```
>  mount /dev/cdrom
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>  mount /cd
> ```
>
> For more details, see `fstab(5)`. Only the user that mounted a 
>   filesystem can unmount it again. If any user should be able
>   to unmount, then use users instead of user in the fstab line.
>   The owner option is similar to the user option, with the restriction
>   that the user must be the owner of the special file. This may be 
>   useful e.g. for `/dev/fd` if a login script makes the console user 
>   owner of this device. The group option is similar, with the 
>   restriction that the user must be member of the group of the special
>   file.

Comment: Hi Faheem, thanks for helping. Can you be more specific which line I should put in /etc/fstab then? (up to it's UUID)

Comment: @MariusHofert there should be a line in `/ec/fstab` for it already. Isn't there?

Comment: ah... see the update. But I have `auto` etc. in there... what do I have to change?

Comment: @MariusHofert that `auto` is for the filesystem. Your options are already good as is, you don't need to change anything. You should already be able to unmount as user, but it should be the same user. What user is your shell script running as? Try manuall mounting and then immediately unmounting as your user account. Does it work or not? If not, give the error.